# Visual Studio showing errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9np3K.png)**i want to change my autosave from off to afterdelay, but it is saying that turn on setting sync, i clicked on setting sync but then it is showing this from settings.json**

```html
"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "recentlyUsed"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check the guidelines on **how to ask** a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing comma and the object is not closed in your screenshot